# Imgur link scraping from subreddits in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, href, reddit, imgur

So far my code successfully manages to lift the HTML code from the 5 results it picks up when given the name of a subreddit. Now I want to do a search for the the imgur links, whether it's for an album, containing /a/ or a single image. I want to then lift this link and send it to another class (imgurdl)

What is the best way, given my current code?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import praw
from urllib2 import urlopen
import urllib2
import sys
from urlparse import urljoin
import config
import imgurdl
import requests

cache = []
soup = BeautifulSoup
def reddit_login():
    r = praw.Reddit(username = USER,
                password = config.password,
                client_id = config.client_id,
                client_secret = config.client_secret,
                user_agent = " v0.3"
                )
    print("***********logged in successfully***********")
    return r

def get_category_links(subredditName, r):
    print("Grabbing subreddit...")
    submissions = r.subreddit(subredditName).hot(limit=5)
    print("Grabbing comments...")
    #comments = subred.comments(limit = 200)
    for submission in submissions:
        htmlSource = requests.get(submission.url).text
        print (htmlSource)


r = reddit_login()
get_category_links(sys.argv[1], r)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? And why not use Reddit's API?

Comment: @KevinMGranger I wasn't aware there was one and I am not familiar with it. Do you have links to documentation and would it allow me to lift a link in the fashion? I haven't tried anything so far.

Comment: To find an imgur link in the HTML code, you could use `re`.

Comment: @BurningKarl could you elaborate please?

Comment: Can you do a text match against `submission.url` in your for loop?

Comment: I'm curious to know if the answer provided below helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url from PRAW and then check to see if it is from imgur within the loop itself and then send it to the appropriate function. This way there would be no need to through the html source.

```
 for submission in submissions:
    link = submission.url
    if "imgur.com/a/" in link:
        #Send to imgur album downloader
    elif link.endswith(".jpg") or link.endswith(".png"):
        #Sent to image downloader
    elif "imgur.com/" in link:
        #Send to single image imgur downloader
```